Cartoon show from the 80's with kids going to sleep and go into a magical world
There was this cartoon I used to watch... kids (usually sad ones) went to sleep, woke up and went through a glowing door that led them to a magical world/forest with animals helping them to become happy once again... anyone remembers?!

Sounds like Sylvanian Families. In each episode a kid is introduced who has some kind of problem. While they are asleep at night they're transported to the Woodman's house who shrinks them so that they can enter a small magical door to the Slyvanian Forest. There the Sylvanian Families help them overcome their problems.
Intro and Outro




Wow! Thank you so much! Indeed that is the show!!!!! :)
